# Undetected Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android-studio, nullpointerexception, libgdx, scene2d

I have an error regarding Null Pointer Exception and I can't find the exact location of the error in my program. I have searched for probable solutions online but I find none of them helpful. I know what Null Pointer Exception is but I can't pinpoint what went wrong in my code. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Here's my code:

LevelOneScreen.java

```
public class LevelOneScreen implements Screen {

    private final ThumbChase app;
    WalkAnimate walkAnimate;
    private Stage stage;
    private Image levelOneImage;
    private Image holdStartImage;
    public Image walkRightImage;
    public Image walkLeftImage;
    public float deltaTime = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();


    public LevelOneScreen(final ThumbChase app){
        this.app = app;
        this.stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(app.screenWidth,app.screenHeight , app.camera));

    }
    @Override
    public void show() {

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
        walkAnimate = new WalkAnimate();

        levelOneBackground();
        holdStart();
        ninjaWalk();                            ==>ERROR1:LevelOneScreen.java:54


    }



    public void holdStart(){
        Texture holdStartTexture = new Texture("HoldStart.png");
        holdStartImage = new Image(holdStartTexture);
        float holdStartImageW = holdStartImage.getWidth();
        float holdStartImageH = holdStartImage.getHeight();
        float holdStartImgWidth = app.screenWidth*0.8f;
        float holdStartImgHeight = holdStartImgWidth *(holdStartImageH/holdStartImageW);
        holdStartImage.isTouchable();
        holdStartImage.setSize(holdStartImgWidth,holdStartImgHeight);
        holdStartImage.setPosition(stage.getWidth()/2-holdStartImgWidth/2,stage.getHeight()/2-holdStartImgHeight/2);
        stage.addActor(holdStartImage);
        holdStartImage.addListener(new ActorGestureListener(){
            public void touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
                holdStartImage.setVisible(false);
            };
        });


        }


    public void levelOneBackground(){
        Texture levelOneTexture = new Texture("BGBlue Resize.png");
        levelOneImage = new Image(levelOneTexture);
        levelOneImage.setSize(app.screenWidth,app.screenHeight);
        levelOneImage.setPosition(0,0);
        stage.addActor(levelOneImage);
        levelOneImage.addListener(new ActorGestureListener(){
            public void touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
                holdStartImage.setVisible(false);
            };
        });
    }
    public void ninjaWalk(){

ERROR2==>   TextureRegion ninjaWalkRight = new TextureRegion(walkAnimate.getCurrentFrameRight());
            TextureRegion ninjaWalkLeft = new TextureRegion(walkAnimate.getCurrentFrameLeft());
            walkRightImage = new Image(ninjaWalkRight);
            walkLeftImage = new Image(ninjaWalkLeft);
            float walkImageW = walkRightImage.getWidth();
            float walkImageH = walkRightImage.getHeight();
            float walkImageWidth = app.screenWidth*0.15f;
            float walkImageHeight = walkImageWidth*(walkImageH/walkImageW);
            walkLeftImage.isTouchable();
            walkRightImage.isTouchable();
            walkRightImage.setSize(walkImageWidth,walkImageHeight);
            walkLeftImage.setSize(walkImageWidth,walkImageHeight);
            walkRightImage.setPosition(stage.getWidth()/2-walkImageWidth/2,0);
            walkLeftImage.setPosition(stage.getWidth()/2-walkImageWidth/2,0);
            walkLeftImage.addAction(moveBy(3f,3f,3f));
            stage.addActor(walkLeftImage);


        }

        @Override
        public void render(float delta) {

            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            walkAnimate.update(deltaTime);
            update(delta);
        }

        public void update(float delta){
            stage.act(delta);
            stage.draw();
            app.batch.begin();

            app.batch.end();
        }

        @Override
        public void resize(int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public void pause() {

        }

        @Override
        public void resume() {

        }

        @Override
        public void hide() {

        }

        @Override
        public void dispose() {
            stage.dispose();

        }
    }
```

WalkAnimate.java

```
public class WalkAnimate {

        public ThumbChase app;
        public Stage stage;


        private Animation walkAnimationRight;
        private Animation walkAnimationLeft;
        private Texture walkSheetRight;
        private Texture walkSheetLeft;
        private TextureRegion[] walkFramesRight;
        private TextureRegion[] walkFramesLeft;
        private TextureRegion   currentFrameRight;
        private TextureRegion   currentFrameLeft;
        private float stateTime;
        private Rectangle bound; //used for positioning and collision detection
        private static final int  FRAME_COLS_WALK = 3;
        private static final int  FRAME_ROWS_WALK= 2;
        private float screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        private float screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        public float currentFrameWidth = (float)(screenHeight*0.15);
        public float currentFrameHeight = (float)(screenHeight*0.15);
        public float walkSheetWidth;
        public float walkSheetHeight;



        public WalkAnimate () {

            walkSheetRight = new Texture("ninjaWalkRight.png");
            walkSheetWidth = walkSheetRight.getWidth();
            walkSheetHeight = walkSheetRight.getWidth();
            TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(walkSheetRight, (int) walkSheetRight.getWidth() / FRAME_COLS_WALK, (int) walkSheetRight.getHeight() / FRAME_ROWS_WALK);
            walkFramesRight = new TextureRegion[FRAME_COLS_WALK * FRAME_ROWS_WALK];
            int index = 0 ;
            for (int i = 0; i < FRAME_ROWS_WALK; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < FRAME_COLS_WALK; j++) {
                    walkFramesRight[index++] = tmp[i][j];
                }
            }
            walkAnimationRight = new Animation(0.044f, walkFramesRight);
            stateTime = 0f;


            walkSheetLeft = new Texture("ninjaWalkLeft.png");
            walkSheetWidth = walkSheetLeft.getWidth();
            walkSheetHeight = walkSheetLeft.getWidth();
            TextureRegion[][] tmp1 = TextureRegion.split(walkSheetLeft, (int) walkSheetRight.getWidth() / FRAME_COLS_WALK, (int)walkSheetLeft.getHeight() / FRAME_ROWS_WALK);
            walkFramesLeft = new TextureRegion[FRAME_COLS_WALK * FRAME_ROWS_WALK];
            int index1 = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < FRAME_ROWS_WALK; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < FRAME_COLS_WALK; j++) {
                    walkFramesLeft[index1++] = tmp1 [i][j];
                }
            }
            walkAnimationLeft = new Animation(0.044f, walkFramesLeft);
            stateTime = 0f;


        }


        public Rectangle getBound(){
            return bound;
        }

        public void update(float delta){
            stateTime += delta;
            currentFrameRight = walkAnimationRight.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
            currentFrameLeft = walkAnimationLeft.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
        }


        public TextureRegion getCurrentFrameRight(){
            return currentFrameRight;

        }
        public TextureRegion getCurrentFrameLeft(){
            return currentFrameLeft;
        }
    }
```

And here's the error:

```
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                   at
> com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion.setRegion(TextureRegion.java:112)
>                                                                                   at
> com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion.<init>(TextureRegion.java:63)
>                                                                                   at
> com.jpfalmazan.thumbchaseninja.GameScreens.LevelOneScreen.show(LevelOneScreen.java:54)
>                                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
>                                                                                   at
> com.jpfalmazan.thumbchaseninja.GameScreens.MenuScreen$1.clicked(MenuScreen.java:82)
>                                                                                   at
> com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ClickListener.touchUp(ClickListener.java:89)
>                                                                                   at
> com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputListener.handle(InputListener.java:58)
>                                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.touchUp(Stage.java:353)
>                                                                                   at
> com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput.processEvents(AndroidInput.java:379)
>                                                                                   at
> com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:457)
>                                                                                   at
> android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1516)
>                                                                                   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

Comment: one of your object instantiation would be causing this, add logs or introduce try catch around the usage of `TextureRegion` statements. You will get it.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/89/exceptions-and-exception-handling/385/catching-an-exception-with-try-catch#t=20161123071434254621

Comment: It didn't help much in detecting the error, thanks though

Comment: I think the problem is at your split method in `WalkAnimate()`. Or the assets are not completely loaded. I would highly recommend using an [AssetManager](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets), see [this post](https://reimerm.de/2016/10/creating-an-assets-manager-for-libgdx-using-kotlin-5/) for an example.

Comment: @Marius I guess you're right that the problem may be in WalkAnimate() because when I replace the textureregion with a texture (I used the badlogic.jpg), the code actually runs. I don't get though where in the walkanimate class is the error since I have already used that code in another project of mine and it works. The only difference is that I used it earlier in spritebatch and this time added it as an actor in stage.

Comment: I will definitely try using AssetManager after studying how it's done.

Comment: Please stop linking new questions that way: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289365/what-to-do-when-an-op-adds-comments-to-their-previous-qa-asking-for-help-on-the

Answer (score 0):

you can find the exact line in logcat logs, you can see the activity name as well as the line of code and by clicking on it you will be redirected to the individual Activity on same line..

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I have tried initializing currentFrameRight and currentFrameLeft in my WalkAnimate constructor and it finally runs, the problem now is that it does not animate but only shows one frame.

Comment: Can you take a look at my question here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136318/how-to-refresh-dependencies-after-adding-freetype-extension-in-android-project

Comment: Guys can you visit my new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971321/how-to-restart-screen-in-libgdx-using-init-methods

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't call `walkAnimate.update(dt)` before calling `walkAnimate.getCurrentFrameRight()` the first time, so `walkAnimate.getCurrentFrameRight()` returns `null`.

Moreover, in `ninjaWalk()` you create two actors (`walkRightImage` and `walkLeftImage`), only add one to the stage and never update the texture of it. You should rework your concept: Create one actor at startup, store it in a field and change the texture of it in your render/update method.

Comment: I've tried what you said and it works but does not animate, only one frame is showing.

Comment: In ninjaWalk() you only get a snapshot of the current texture and set it to the actor. You have to update the actor's texture every frame.

Comment: Can I ask for help on how can I do that? I have already updated walkAnimate by calling walkAnimate.update(deltaTime) in the show method right before calling ninjaWalk() and the image does not animate. I will gladly mark your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

One of your textures is either named wrong, or you are attempting to access it before it has been loaded.

You can tell by this exception;

```
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion.setRegion(TextureRegion.java:112)
```

This mean that the texture region cannot map the texture identifier to a valid texture in your program, so either `ninjaWalkRight` or `ninjaWalkLeft` does not exist or is not loaded.

If you are using texture packer then ensure your files are called `ninjaWalkRight` and `ninjaWalkLeft`.

Also use the `AssetManager` to ensure these files are loaded before trying to access them as that may be an issue also.

Comment: Can you take a look at my question here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136318/how-to-refresh-dependencies-after-adding-freetype-extension-in-android-project